# SQL query to get maximum value for each day

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

So I have a table that looks something like this:

[image]

Now, I want the max `totalcst` for both days, something like this:

[image]

I tried using different variations of max and the Row_number funtion but still can't seem to get the result I want. My query:

```
select date,pid,max(quan*cst), totalcst
from dbo.test1
group by date, pid
```

But this returns all the records. So if somebody can point me towards the right direction, that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER` should work just fine:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [date] ORDER BY totalcst)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  [date],
        pid,
        totalcst
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple way:

```
select t.*
from test1 t
where t.totalcst = (select max(t2.totalcst) from test1 t2 where t2.date = t.date);
```

This often has the best performance if you have an index on `(date, totalcst)`.  Of course, `row_number()`/`rank()` is also a very acceptable solution:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by date order by totalcst desc) as seqnum
      from test1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: thank you. this works perfectly. i was including the id field in the partition by.